# How to get the actual data for select options in quasar?

Tags: vue.js, axios, quasar-framework, quasar

---

I am getting [object Object] as select option values

```
<q-select
v-model="product_type"
:options="types"
option-label="label"
option-value="type_name"
label="Product Type"
emit-value
map-options
/>
```

---

I am getting [object Object] as select option values

```
export default {
data () {
    return {
        types: []
    }
},
created () {
    this.$axios.get(['http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/lailen-inventory/types'])
        .then(res => {
            this.types = res.data.types
        }).catch(errors => {
            console.log(errors)
        })
}
}
```

Comment: Finally i realise where i made a mistake! In case anyone have this error change option-label="label" to "category_name"